# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code block, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3fLk5fag/

But when I click to `generate` button, getting this error:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `[name=ORDER_PNAME[]]`

Before inputs has no errors.

Whats the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to quote that name:

```
[name='ORDER_PNAME[]']
```

Those brackets (`[ ]`) are what are causing the problem.

Your fiddle also has problems with a misplaced `console.log(value)`, and a missing library for that md5 hashing.